# recursive lambda via reference

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Is this code correct?

```
std::function<int(int)> f = [&f](int n) -> int
{
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1);
};

int x = f(42);
```

Is there any potential problem with object construction before it passed as reference to lambda? Or this code absolutely correct?

Capturing f by value leads to crash in msvc2010 compiler.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the recursion but why are you capturing the lambda by reference?

Comment: @JaredPar otherwise it crashes in msvc2010 compiler :)

Comment: @JaredPar: because if he captured it by value, he'd get a copy of the function object when the lambda was created, BEFORE f was initialized?  Undefined behavior

Comment: @Xeo: I think the question is different enough to stand on its own. It's asking about whether this is legal C++11 code; that question is about the use of `auto funcname` rather than `std::function<> funcname`.

Comment: @Nicol: Yep, noticed that after my vote though... I deleted the comment so it wouldn't encourage other close votes. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine, so long as you follow the rules of references to stack variables stored in lambdas. It is well-defined C++11 code.